# actions of orientation-preserving maps on homology group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, mapping-class-groups

Let $M$ be a orientable, connected, closed n-manifold with all of its homology group $H_{*}(M;Z)$ torsion-free. $f: M \rightarrow M $ is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism, and $f_{*,k}: H_{k}(M;Z) \rightarrow H_{k}(M;Z) $ is the induced automorphism of $f$ on  homology groups of integral coefficient.
My question is : $\forall k \ge 0$,Is the determinant $det(f_{*,k}) =1$?
For n=1,it is just the definition of orientation-preserving homeo.
For n=2,Here is an algebraically proof (I don't know a geometric one which don't use some algebraic facts):since $H_{1}(S_g;Z)$ have a symplectic structure ( which I mean the one induced from intersection number), so $f_{*,1}$ is a symplectic automorphism, so  $det(f_{*,1}) =1$.

Comment: No, this is false. Take $M=S^2\times S^2$, with $f(x,y)=(y,x)$. 
It preserves the orientation and exchanges the two generators of $H_2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ (corresponding to the two factors), hence the determinant of $f_*$ on $H_2$ is $-1$.